# Youtube API: allow users comment on youtube videos from my wordpress website

Tags: api, youtube

is there any one who can help me implement a script or a wordpress plug-in that allows users registered in youtube to comment on the videos posted in my wordpress website and that comment goes directly to youtube. I tried several times to make that using the php api but i am not professional with php.
Thanks